# Camera and Object tracking

Tags: tracking

I want to track one particle in a video and have some questions:

- What data files are compatible with the program?
- What data (position, Velocity of the particle,…) will be obtain?
- Is the software for free or are there some costs?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please focus your post on one question. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need, each as a separate post.

Comment: Start with https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The software is 100% free

here is a list of supported video formats

https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/video_formats.html

But as far as motion tracking it depends if the camera is moving or not.

If the camera is moving, you can find out how it was moved by tracking things in the scene that dont move.

But if the camera is stationary, and you simply want to track a moving target.
Then you can do some simple math by finding out at what frame rate the video was recorded,
then checking how much the particle moved over how many frames.

Comment: The camera is stationary. But is it also possible to track a bigger particle? (3-5 cm)

Comment: Well, motion tracking is recorder by using "markers". A Marker is a tiny box that tracks a pattern of pixels. You can change the size of the marker to cover more pixels or less pixels. And the more markers you have per object/particle, the better tracking result you will get.